# How to hide or remove items in File menu in Office Web Apps

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, office-web-apps, security-trimming

Is there a way I can remove or hide the options in Office Web Apps for Save As, Print and Share?

I've read something saying it might be possible with Active Directory Rights Management Services, but I don't have access to the active directory and wouldn't know where to begin.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? IMO it's still not possible in SharePoint 2016 with Office Online Server... See my question: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/204696/office-online-server-hide-buttons

Comment: @Boland I was never able to find a solution to this, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding below styles to your master page

```
#faPrint-Menu32 {
    display: none;
}

#faShare-Menu32 {
    display: none;
}

#faSaveAs-Menu32 {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Where on the master page would I add these?

Comment: You can add inside `<head>` section

Comment: I copied the code into a `<style type="text/css">` tag after `<head>` and it did not hide the options.

Answer (score 0):

To hide the toolbars you just have to set the value of the URL variable "action" to "embedview". Ex:
https://site/_layouts/15/WopiFrame2.aspx?sourcedoc=...&file=...&**action=embedview**